# Showing equality based on 2 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

Having the following equations:
$h_1 + l_2 = 3^n = l_1 + h_2$ and $l_1 + h_1 = l_2 + h_2$ we are supposed to infer that $h_1 = h_2$ and $l_1 = l_2$
I can prove it as follows:
$l_1 + h_1 = l_2 + h_2$
$l_1 + 3^n - l_2 = l_2 + 3^n - l_1$
$l_1 - l_2 = l_2 - l_1$
$2l_1 = 2l_2$
$l1 = l2$

And then:
$h_1 + l_2 = 3^n$
$h_1 = 3^n - l_2 = 3^n - l_1$  (since $l_1 = l_2$)
$h2 = 3^n - l_1$
Hence $h_1 = h_2$

Is my approach correct? I have a feeling that there is a shorter way to do the inference that I am missing

Comment: That works. Your way is pretty short. Another way is to show that $ (h_1 + l_2) + (l_1 + h_1) =( l_1 + h_2) + (l_2 + h_2)$ so $ 2 h_1 = 2 h_2$, and likewise for the $l$'s.

Comment: Very clear proof. I also think it's a good solution.